# How to render a custom block in a twig file?

Tags: theming, blocks

I created a custom block named "Alert Bar" in the "navigation" region and I want to render it in my header file.

My header file currently has code like this to render the blocks -

```
{% if page.navigation or page.navigation_collapsible %}
  {% block navbar %}
    {% if no_head != 'true' %}
      {% include '@eventsns/components/navbar.html.twig' with incs %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
```

Can I do something like `{% block alertbar %}` to display the alert bar block? The machine name says it is "alertbar" but I'm not sure if that's the correct variable since it does not render anything.

Comment: block in twig is not the same as block in drupal, if that's what you are thinking.

Answer (score 2):

1. [block in twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/block.html) are a "placedholder" to re-use text. They aren't drupal blocks
2. The easiest way as far I know to print a block is [to use twig tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak). The could should be `{{ drupal_entity('block', 'block_id', check_access=false) }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're rendering a custom block, you might want to use `block_content` instead.

1. Block: `{{ drupal_entity('block', 'block_id', check_access=false) }}`
2. Block Content: `{{ drupal_entity('block_content', 'content_block_id') }}`

[Documentation: Rendering Blocks with Twig](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak)